# MFMessageComposeViewController shows an black screen

Tags: objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm using the following code to send in-app sms.

```
NSString *message = @"this ia the message";
MFMessageComposeViewController *TextSheet = ([MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]);
TextSheet.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[TextSheet setBody:message];
TextSheet.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"0549999999", @"0548888888", nil];
[self presentViewController:TextSheet animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

I try it on a real device iPhone 5C with IOS 7 and its shows a black
screen only. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ([MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]);
never do alloc without init ! probably this will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code - most importantly, you're not initializing your `MFMessageComposeViewController` correctly. You need to call `alloc` and `init`.

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *textSheet = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

You could also tidy up your recipients list by using a literal array:

```
textSheet.recipients = @[ @"0549999999", @"0548888888" ];
```

Finally, your `nil` that you're passing for the completion block should not be capitalized:

```
[self presentViewController:textSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: thank you very much!!! the init was the problem.